# UNION on Different CTEs

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, union, common-table-expression

Is it possible to UNION two separate CTEs?  Say I have the following 2 query sets:

```
;WITH [fu] AS (SELECT 1 AS [data]),
[bar] AS (SELECT 5 AS [data])
SELECT a.[data] AS [Val1], b.[data] AS [Val2], (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
FROM [fu] a JOIN [bar] b ON 1=1

;WITH [fu] AS (SELECT 3 AS [data]),
[bar] AS (SELECT 8 AS [data])
SELECT a.[data] AS [Val1], b.[data] AS [Val2], (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
FROM [fu] a JOIN [bar] b ON 1=1
```

I want the different [data] values from each CTE along with the sum of them in the same record.  Placing a UNION between the CTEs fails (SQL Server 2014 Developer).  Is there valid SQL that can output both CTEs as part of the same (2-line, in this case) record set?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Do you really want these fake tables or is that just sample data?

Comment: I used the fake tables to make as simple an example as possible.  I'm interested in knowing if combining the two sets of results is even possible and if so, how.  Any answer that uses the fake data is great.

Comment: . . I'm a bit lost on the example.  You have four CTEs with two names.  The question has lost any connection to real tables.

Comment: You can keep adding queries to a single CTE, e.g. `with Foo1 as (...), Bar1 as (...), FooBar1 as (... Foo1 cross join Bar 1 ...), Foo2 as (...), Bar2 as (...), FooBar2 as (... Foo2 cross join Bar2 ...) select ... from FooBar1 union all FooBar2 ...;`. There can only be a single statement that uses the result(s) from the CTE queries, e.g. the final `select`.

Comment: Yup, your reply put me onto the solution I was looking for..  Keep on adding multiple queries in the CTE and then UNION the results in the SELECT.  Revised code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should've been clearer that my initial challenge was to take some number of query pairs (1 pair in my example, each producing a single datapoint), combine them into single records and then add a third field that does some math on the two data fields.  From there I needed to UNION the single-record data/math records into a single result set.  Using a CTE was definitely the right track but thanks HABO for the thought which gave me the SQL I needed..

```
;WITH [fu_1] AS (SELECT 1 AS [data]),
[bar_1] AS (SELECT 5 AS [data]),
[fu_2] AS (SELECT 3 AS [data]),
[bar_2] AS (SELECT 8 AS [data])
SELECT a.[data] AS [Val1], b.[data] AS [Val2], (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
FROM [fu_1] a JOIN [bar_1] b ON 1=1
UNION
SELECT a.[data] AS [Val1], b.[data] AS [Val2], (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
FROM [fu_2] a JOIN [bar_2] b ON 1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply turn the CTEs to subqueries?

```
SELECT ... -- your final logic goes here
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.[data] AS [Val1], 
        b.[data] AS [Val2], 
        (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS [data]) a 
    JOIN (SELECT 5 AS [data]) b ON 1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        a.[data] AS [Val1], 
        b.[data] AS [Val2], 
        (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
    FROM (SELECT 3 AS [data]) a 
    JOIN (SELECT 8 AS [data]) b ON 1=1
) t
```

Otherwise, you need to declare all the CTE first, and then use them in the union. This means that you cannot reuse the same CTE alias twice for two different queries, so:

```
WITH 
    [fu1] AS (SELECT 1 AS [data]),
    [bar1] AS (SELECT 5 AS [data]),
    [fu2] AS (SELECT 3 AS [data]),
    [bar2] AS (SELECT 8 AS [data])
SELECT ... -- your final logic goes here    
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.[data] AS [Val1], 
        b.[data] AS [Val2], 
        (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
    FROM [fu1] a 
    JOIN [bar1] b ON 1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        a.[data] AS [Val1], 
        b.[data] AS [Val2], 
        (a.[data] + b.[data]) AS [Math] 
    FROM [fu2] a 
    JOIN [bar2] b ON 1=1
) t
```